# A set of integers whose elements all divide $2015^{200}$ but do not divide each other

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $S$ be a set of natural numbers,such that each element divides $2015^{200}$ but for no two elements $a$ and $b$, $a|b$. Find the maximum number of elements in $S$ .

$2015^{200}=(5\cdot 13\cdot 31)^{200}$

Hence each element is of the form $5^p13^q31^r$ where $p,q,r$ lie between $0$ and $200$, inclusive.The given condition also says that for no two elements $5^p13^q31^r$ and $5^a13^b31^c$,$p\le a,q\le b,r\le c$.

I have tried to guess the solution by fixing the value of $a$ and then letting $b$ and $c$ run through the range of values that they are allowed to take.But I keep getting confused again and again.

I will appreciate any sort of comment,hint or answer.

**EDIT:**

As has been noted in the comments below,a trivial upper bound is $201^2$. But is this achievable?Can we show that it's not?Because then we may gain some insight.

Comment: One way of constructing large examples of such sets is to take $S_k = \{5^p13^q31^r\colon 0\le p,q,r\le200,\, p+q+r=k\}$. You could start by determining which $k$ makes $S_k$ largest; perhaps that's the optimal example. Also a trivial upper bound is $(201)^2$, since if $S$ is larger than that, by the pigeonhole principle it must contain two elements with $p$ and $q$ both equal.

Comment: @GregMartin,how do we deal with the restrictions on $p,q,r$?Stars and bars won't work.

Comment: @GregMartin $k=300$ would do best among such sets with $30301$ terms, though far short of $201^2=40401$. Of course no assurance this is close to the actual maximum.

Comment: @Macavity is there any non-computational way to verify that $k=300$ would do the best?

Comment: @rah4927 Its the coefficient of $x^k$ in $\dfrac{(1-x^{201})^3}{(1-x)^3}$, which can be found through modest amount of effort and tabled to find the max. Finding a closed form for it and then the maximum seems more effort.

Comment: @Macavity,so the coefficients form a unimodal sequence.We only need to find the coefficient of $x^{300}$.Am I right?

Comment: @rah4927 it is unimodal, so we need only to check $k=299, 300, 301$ to verify.  Of course there is no guarantee the approach answers the OP.

Comment: @Macavity why do we need to check $k=299,300,301$?Won't $k=300$ suffice?

Comment: That needs unimodal, symmetric and maximum is not at borders, all of which happen to be true, but need to be shown. Simpler to check three numbers and verify.

Comment: The "trivial" upper bound $201^2$ can be improved... to $201^2 - 1$.  This follows recursively from the fact that the $2\times 2\times 2$ cube can be partitioned into three disjoint chains, so the largest antichain in that case is width $3$, rather than $4$.

Comment: The [OEIS entry A096825](https://oeis.org/A096825) for this has generating functions, sample code and references (size of the largest antichain in the divisor poset).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that any two distinct elements $5^{p_1} 13^{q_1} 31^{r_1}$ and $5^{p_2} 13^{q_2} 31^{r_2}$ are incomparable (neither divides the other) if $p_1 + q_1 + r_1 = p_2 + q_2 + r_2$.  So a mutually incomparable set is given by
$$
S_n = \left\{5^p 13^q 31^r \;\big\vert\; p+q+r=n;\; 0\le p,q,r \le 200\right\}
$$
for any $n$.  The size of this set is maximal when $n=300$ (*).  To show that this is the *largest* mutually incomparable set, we can apply [Dilworth's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem), which says that if an antichain $A$ has cardinality equal to that of a partition $P$ of the set into chains, then that antichain is maximal.  A corresponding partition here is given by (the transitive closure of) the following equivalence relation: if $x=5^p 13^q 31^r$, then

- If $p+q+r\equiv 0$ (mod $3$), $x \sim 5x$,
- If $p+q+r\equiv 1$ (mod $3$), $x \sim 13x$, and
- If $p+q+r\equiv 2$ (mod $3$), $x \sim 31x$.

The equivalence relation links every triple $(p,q,r)$ to a unique triple with $p+q+r=300$, and does so while staying inside the box $0\le p,q,r \le 200$.  (The latter property is key, since it distinguishes, say, $S_{300}$ from the much smaller $S_{200}$.)

---

Note on evaluating $|S_n|$:

Only the restrictions $p,q,r\ge 0$ apply for $0 \le n\le 200$, so the number of ways to choose $(p,q,r)$ summing to $n$ in that range is
$$|S_n|=1+2+\ldots+n+(n+1)=\frac{1}{2}(n+1)(n+2).$$  For $200<n \le 300$, we have to subtract out cases where one of the terms (and it can be only one) is larger than $200$: there are $$1+2+\ldots+(n-200)=\frac{1}{2}(n-200)(n-199)$$ cases where each of $p,q,r$ is greater than $200$.  So the total size is
$$
|S_n|=\frac{1}{2}(n+1)(n+2)-\frac{3}{2}(n-200)(n-199)
$$
in this range.  (So $|S_{300}|=30301=|S_{299}|+1$.) Finally, for $n>300$, we can use symmetry, because $|S_{n}|=|S_{600-n}|$.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this necessarily stays inside the box.  (e.g. if $(p,q,r)=(200,1,0)$, how do you reach $S_{300}$?).

Comment: To find $|S_n|$ you can use inclusion exclusion without thinking about different cases. The number of integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 \, + \; ... \, + \, x_k = n$ where $0 \leq x_i < \mu$ is $$\sum_{i=0}^\gamma \; (-1)^i {k \choose i} {n+k-1-i\mu \choose k-1}$$ where $\gamma = \min\{k, \lfloor \tfrac{n}{\mu} \rfloor \}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.However,as I am not yet familiar with order theory,can you please state what Dilworth's theorem tells us in the context of this problem?