# Let $T$ be the set of all positive integer divisors of $2004^{100}$. Size of largest subset $S$ of $T$ such that no element in $S$ divides another?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

*I am getting an answer slightly over $100^2$. Is this right (working below), or is there a better way of selecting elements of S?*

The following question appeared on the 2004 Canada National Olympiad:

> Let $T$ be the set of all positive integer divisors of $2004^{100}$. What is the largest possible number of elements of a subset $S$ of $T$ such that no element in $S$ divides any other element in $S$?

---

Factorising, $2004 = 2^2\cdot3\cdot167$. So any element of $T$ is of the form

$2^p 3^q 167^r\text{ with }0\le{p}\le200,0\le{q}\le100,0\le{r}\le100 \tag{1}$

We start by excluding from $S$ the element mapping to $p=q=r=0$ because $1$ divides any natural number.

> $\text{The key to the method is to choose elements so that the sum }p+q+r\text{ is always the same. Then distinct elements cannot be multiples.}\\$
>  $\text{For }p=0:\text{ choose all }q,r\text{ s.t. }q+r=200:2^{0}3^{100}167^{100}$
>  $\text{For }p=1:\text{ choose all }q,r\text{ s.t. }q+r=199:2^{1}3^{100}167^{99},2^{1}3^{99}167^{100}\\{\cdots}$
>  $\text{For }p=100:\text{ choose all }q,r\text{ s.t. }q+r=100:2^{100}3^{100}167^{0},\dots,2^{100}3^{0}167^{100}$ 
>  $\text{For }p=101:\text{ choose all }q,r\text{ s.t. }q+r=99:2^{101}3^{99}167^{0},\dots,2^{101}3^{0}167^{99}\\{\cdots}$
>  $\text{For }p=200:\text{ choose all }q,r\text{ s.t. }q+r=0:2^{200}3^{0}167^{0}\\\text{So }\\ \max|S| = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{101}{k}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{100}{k}=\frac{1}{2}101\cdot102+\frac{1}{2}100\cdot101=101^2=10201\\$

Comment: The right numerical answer. That one cannot do better is not proved.

Comment: Do you know how to show that this is optimal?  Hint: for $q,r\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,100\}$, consider the set $S_{q,r}$ consisting of all $2^p3^q167^r$ with $p\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,200\}$.

Comment: For fun: Let $T$ be the set of all positive integers from $1$ to $2004^{100}$. What is the largest possible number of elements of a subset $S$ of $T$ such that no element in $S$ divides any other element in $S$?

Comment: For a given $(q,r)$ only one choice of $p$ is possible, or else there will certainly be multiples in this subset. Since all possible $(q,r)$ were used, the answer is maximal.

Comment: Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116160/a-set-of-integers-whose-elements-all-divide-2015200-but-do-not-divide-each?rq=1

Comment: @Macavity - Thanks. That's a very interesting discussion, especially the mention of Dilworth's Theorem. (FWIW, I think 2004 was an easier case than 2015).