# Find the maximal number of elements of such subset $S$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, inequality

> Let $T$ be the set of all positive factor of $n= 2004^{2010}$. Suppose that $S$ be an arbitrary nonempty subset of $T$ satisfying the fact of all $a$, $b$ belong to $S$ and $a>b$ then $a$ not divisible $b$. Find the maximal number of elements of such subset $S$

I don't have any idea for this problem. It's very interesting but strange.

Comment: This looks substantially the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378626/), which is linked to the right under "Related."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A set of integers whose elements all divide $2015^{200}$ but do not divide each other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116160/a-set-of-integers-whose-elements-all-divide-2015200-but-do-not-divide-each)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Members of $T$ are of the form $2^r 3^s 167^t$ where $0 \le r \le 4020$, $0 \le s \le 2010$ and $0 \le t \le 2010$.  If $a = 2^r 3^s 167^t$ and $b = 2^u 3^v 167^w$ are distinct members of $S$, you need at least one of $r-u$, $s-v$, $t-w$ to be strictly positive and at least one strictly negative.  You might consider $S$ of the form $\{2^r 3^s 167^t\; : 0 \le r\le 4020,\; 0 \le s\le 2010,\; 0 \le t\le 2010,\; r+s+t = m\}$ for suitable $m$.